# When using blazeDS's proxy-config throw faultDetail="Connection refused: connect"

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have created a XML file directly under the webroot, named index.jsp, the contents are as follow:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
<product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <description>Product 1 is good</description>
    <price>5</price>
</product>

<product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <description>Product 2 is good</description>
    <price>15</price>
</product>

<product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <description>Product 2 is good</description>
    <price>25</price>
</product>   
</catalog>
```

And in proxy-config.xml under the WEB-INF/flex:

```
<destination id="getXML">
 <properties>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/FlexTest/index.jsp</url>
 </properties>
</destination>
```

In the main.mxml, the httpservice as follow:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="httpService" destination="getXML" useProxy="true" />
```

Corresponding DataGrid:

```
 <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{httpService.lastResult.catalog.product}" x="405" y="130" width="329" height="166"/>
```

But when I click the button to execute httpService.send(), some errors has been thrown up as follow:

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Error sending request" faultCode="Server.Proxy.Request.Failed" faultDetail="Connection refused: connect"]
```

at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:290]
 at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:58]
 at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:103]
 at NetConnectionMessageResponder/statusHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:581]
 at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/status()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:222]

I hope someone could help me solve it out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to give to your HTTPService an url, like

```
<mx:HTTPService id="httpService" url="http://localhost:8080/FlexTest/index.jsp" destination="getXML" useProxy="true"/>
```